# Jenkins: empty error window when adding credential

Tags: jenkins, credentials

I have Jenkins Jenkins ver. 2.138.2 running on a CentOS 7 machine, inside Docker. I'm accessing the server from another machine, through IPv6 in the same local network (which probably doesn't really matter because of IPv6).

My problem is, when I try to add a new Credential of any type, either with, or without the right required data, when I click the Add button, I see a window titled with "Error" show up.

Nothing is in that window, it doesn't even close the credentials window and of course, I can't see the added credential in the dropdown.

Anybody has a solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: I managed to get it working with a PUTTY tunnel, where I effectively become the localhost on the machine running docker. Why is this not working from outside?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when I configured the credential in Jenkins running on a docker container which is running on mac. After I did the same thing in Jenkins running on a docker container which is running on Ubuntu, the issue disappeared.